# Discard all local changes and go back to the last pulled version

Tags: git

How I could in git discard all local changes/commits and go back to the last pulled version (command has to be in one String(field))?

Answer (score 1):

You can [reset](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) your branch to the revision on in the remote repo:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard <remote-name>/<branch-name>
```

Example:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Or find the commit SHA-1 of the "pulled version" and do:

```
git reset --hard <commit SHA-1>
```

To safe your (committed) work before you go back:

```
git checkout -b my-work
```

Note: Think twice before using `git reset --hard`, you will lose all your uncommitted changes!